# Accessing the google tag manager field values in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

[image]

Where can i check for Field values i set for a tag in google tag manager in the google analytics

Answer (score 1):

You are looking in the wrong place. "Fields to set" is for configuration options for Google Analytics (cookie name, ip anonymization, transport mode etc). They are not for transmitting data.

If you want to send custom data in Google Analytics you can refer to the [documentation for custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829) (dimensions being text fields, and metrics being number fields). You can then use custom dimensions as secondary dimensions standardard reports, or use custom dimensions and metrics in in custom reports, via  the API, or in tools like Google Sheets or Data Studio.